# Binding properties of an Object to an input

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table containing alphabet letters with corresponding images. Each letter opens a Modal containing more images.
I want to be able to select a new image for a letter in the modal, and when I press confirm, to update the letter image in the table.
Here's how it looks:

[image: The table containing alphabet]

[image: The modal for choosing image]

My code for generating the table:

```html
<div id="vue-app">

    <section class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 mr-5 overflow-auto"  style="max-height: 50vw; overflow-y: scroll">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered text-center overflow-auto">
                        <thead class="table-info">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Letter</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="(value,key) in student_letters ">
                                    <td class="align-middle"><p style="font-size:2.5em;"><b>[[key]]</b></p></td>
                                    <td class="align-middle">
                                        <button v-if="value == null" class="btn btn-info" v-bind:id=" 'btn_' + key" data-toggle="modal" v-bind:data-target=" '#' + key"><b>+</b></button>
                                        <img v-else class="btn" v-bind:id=" 'btn_' + key" data-toggle="modal" v-bind:data-target=" '#' + key" v-bind:src="value.letter_img" v-bind:alt="key" style="height: 100%; width: 7vw; object-fit: cover;">
                                    </td>   
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col ml-5">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Preview:</h5>
                          <hr>
                          <p class="card-text">Manage your students</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

My code for generating the modals (Note, I use Django here with {{ }} brackets. for Vue I use [[ ]]):

```html
<section>
    {% for key, letter in letter_dict.items %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="{{ key }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="row text-center mt-4">
                            <div class="containter px-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    {% for l in all_letters %}
                                        {% if l.letter == key %}
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input id="img-radio" type="radio" name="modal_letter" value="{{ l.letter_img.url }}" v-model="message">
                                                    <img src="{{ l.letter_img.url }}" alt="Option 2">
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row text-center mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary"><b>Upload New</b></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

My Vue script:

```js
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#vue-app',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data () {
          return {
            info: {},
            student_letters: { 
                            "a": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "b": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "c": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "d": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "e": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "f": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "g": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "h": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "i": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "j": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "k": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "l": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "m": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "n": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "o": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "p": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "q": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "r": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "s": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "t": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "u": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "v": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "w": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "x": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "y": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null}, 
                            "z": {id:null, letter:null, letter_name:null, letter_img:null} },
            message: "hello",
          }
        },
        mounted () {
            const student_pk = { pk: this.$refs.student_info.id};

            axios
            .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/letters/list/')
            .then(response => (this.info = response.data));

            axios
            .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/util/get_student_letters/', student_pk)
            .then(response => (Object.assign(this.student_letters, response.data)));
        }
      })
</script>
```

The reason why I'm having trouble is because the table is generated by data that I get through an API call, and saving it in an object called "student_letters", heres how it looks:

[image: student_letters object]

And I don't know how to "bind" the properties of the Object to their corresponding cells in the table.

Basically, after selecting a new image in the modal and hitting confirm, I want to be able to reactively change the corresponding property (letter_img) in my "student_letters" object, and also change the cell in the table.